# how can I boot linux on ARM platform with opengl and Qt?

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, arm, boot

I want to compile image of Linux kernel with optimized start up time (2 or 3 seconds). and then port to ARM A10 cpu with Opengl and Qt. Do you anyone have experienced ?

Comment: [eLinux article](http://elinux.org/images/b/b3/Elce11_koen.pdf), [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/), and  [Qt one second boot](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2011/1-second-linux-boot-to-qt/?ModPagespeed=noscript)... you can insert a `delay` to make it 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two TI Sitara SoCs working with Qt Embedded (framebuffer driver) using [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). BR provides both Qt4 and Qt5. There was an effort to bring multimedia support. See this [GSoC report](http://elinux.org/Buildroot%3aGSoC2013_ARM_Multimedia).

Comment: Buildroot is a good choice, and you can look at http://linux-sunxi.org/Buildroot#Build_buildroot_image_for_A10 for the A10 port. Your startup time though will depend on what user interface needs to come up on display and what applications need to startup.

Comment: I want to have 2 or 3 seconds in startup time